# Segmentation fault when incrementing integer from struct (C)

Tags: c, struct

I'm currently writing a function for an assignment, and when I attempt to increment a count variable, a segmentation fault occurs.

```
void createVar(char *varname, char *value) {
    int val = vars->count;

    if (val >= 1) {
        int index = varIndex(varname); 

        if (index != -1) {
            vars->varArray[index]->value = value;
            return;
        } else {
            vars->varArray = (variables_ **) realloc(vars->varArray, sizeof(variables_ *) * (val + 1));
        }
    }
    printf("count= %d\n", vars->count); //testing purposes
    vars->varArray[val] = malloc(sizeof(variables_));
    vars->varArray[val]->varname = varname;
    vars->varArray[val]->value = value;
    vars->count++; //incrementing count 
}
```

I found that the line `vars->count++;` is causing the fault, however I am not sure how to fix this.

To include some context, these are the structs addressed in the above code:

```
typedef struct variables {
    char *varname;
    char *value;
} variables_;

typedef struct variableArray {
    variables_ **varArray;
    int count;
} variableArray_;
variableArray_ *vars;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: `sizeof(variables_) * val` should be `sizeof(variables_ *) * val`.  That won't fix your problem, but it's a pretty severe bug.  Remember, you're allocating an array of *pointers*, not structs.

Comment: Noted, thank you :)

Comment: I allocated `vars` in a separate function; could you kindly check if these lines are correct?   `vars = malloc(sizeof(variableArray_));
    vars->count = 0;
    vars->varArray = calloc(1, sizeof(variables_));`

Comment: What would you recommend changing from `vars->varArray = calloc(1, sizeof(variables_));`? Also, I've updated the post, thank you :)

Comment: After all of these changes, I'm still confused as to how I'm getting a segmentation fault when incrementing the `vars->count` :/

Comment: No worries. I've found where the segmentation fault is stemming from - it's from a completely unrelated function. However the help you've given me was very appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

Restructure this code; something is very wrong.

You are using `val` and `index` somewhat incoherently and are probably trashing memory because they're both being used as indices into the array but the piece that uses `val` is not coherent with the piece that uses `index`.

It's almost like `vars->varArray[val]` is intended to be `vars[val].varArray[index]` but the whole of the code has to change for this to work.